# Basic event listener throws error ('undefined is not a function')

Tags: javascript, function, events

I ran into a problem when trying to add an event listener to a class.

Basically I want it to execute some JS code when something with the class 'col' is clicked

```
document.getElementByClassName("col").addEventListener("click", randomOutput);

function randomOutput(){
    alert("Test");
}
```

Instead of it actually executing the randomOutput function it throws an error. 'undefined is not a function'.

Comment: You are defining the function *after* assigning it to the eventListener. Move your function up.

Comment: @Evilzebra I moved the function above the eventListener but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you need to define your function `randomOutput` before assigning it to the listener.

I am also seeing `getElementByClassName` which is not a function, it should be `getElementsByClassName`.

And lastly, you can only add an event listener to one element. So you must use `document.getElementsByClassName("col")[0].addEventListener("click", randomOutput);` or write some code to loop through each element and add the listener.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to chain `addEventListener()` to the result of `document.getElementByClassName("col");`. `document.getElementByClassName` is invalid and should be `document.getElementsByClassName`.

```
(function () {
   var randomOutput = function {
       alert("Test");
   }

   var els = document.getElementsByClassName("col");

   for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
      els[i].addEventListener("click", randomOutput);
   }
})();
```

Comment: This is wrong, class selector does *not* need to start with a period when using `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Thank you. Too used to CSS-spec selectors.